# few very odd Performance counter using WMI or System.Diagnostics class

Tags: c#, wmi-query

I want to get few performance counter using WMI query/System.Diagnostics class(C#.net).

1> Cache Total Hit Ratio

2> Cache Total Turnover Rate

3> Cache Total Entries

4> Web Service - Current Connections

5> Web Service - Connections Attempts per second

6> Split IO per second

I tried to find out using perfmon exe in control panel, but not able to get anything.
Any one can please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete article showing how to retrieve Performance Counters using WQL (WMI Querying Language)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx

And here is how to access using C#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t90y2y1%28v=VS.71%29.aspx